# Inequality about moments of a random variable and of its conditional expectation

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

This is a follow-up to a question I asked earlier: [Moments of a random variable and of its conditional expectation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210969/moments-of-a-random-variable-and-of-its-conditional-expectation)

My claim turned out to be false. Here is a new claim.

Let $X$ be a bounded random variable with $\mathbb{E}X=0$. Since $X$ is bounded, all its moments exist. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be any $\sigma$-field and let $Y:=\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}].$ I am interested in proving the following inequality relating even moments of $X$ and even moments of $Y:$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\rfloor}\frac{(k-2i)[\mathbb{E}X^{2i}\mathbb{E}Y^{2(k-i)} -\mathbb{E}X^{2(k-i)}\mathbb{E}Y^{2i}]}{(2i-1)(2i)(2k-2i-1)(2k-2i)}\leq 0~.$$

It would have sufficed to show that the quantity in square brackets is non-positive, but as the answer provided to my earlier question showed, this is not true in general.

Any idea what tools might help me prove this?

**EDIT:**

I wanted to prove that a certain power series with even powers yielded a decreasing function (which was confirmed by experiment), and one way to prove it was to show that each co-efficient was non-positive. By choosing the specific random variables you posted on my previous question, I discovered that the power series is not in fact, decreasing everywhere and so the claim I posted in this post must be false as well. I apologize for posting this.

Comment: This seems like a very specific inequality. Is there any strong intuition for why this should be true?

Comment: I wanted to prove that a certain power series with even powers yielded a decreasing function (which was confirmed by experiment), and one way to prove it was to show that each co-efficient was non-positive. By choosing the specific random variables you posted on my previous question, I discovered that the power series is not in fact, decreasing everywhere and so the claim I posted in this post must be false as well. I apologize for posting this.

Comment: So probably it would be a good idea to edit the question, saying at the bottom of what's there that you have resolved it using the example from the previous question.